# Remove internationalization funcion

Tags: python, awk, sed

Can someone suggest me how to remove internationalization function from the code (via `sed/awk/perl/python`)?

```
printf(mail, _i18n_msg_get(ls_catd , NL_SETN, 408, "Notification reported at %s"), /* catgets 408 */)
```

should becode just:

```
printf(mail)
```

Comment: 1st thing you have to be clear in your question, 2nd thing you have to use code tags for samples not for text and 3rd thing always show your efforts in your post which you have put in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/,[^)]*\)[^)]*//' file
```

The regex `,[^)]*\)[^)]*` would match to the code you desire to be removed, i.e. start from the first comma to the last forward slash. `-r` allows `sed` to use extended regular expressions.

Comment: -r will only work with GNU sed. If you use -E instead it'll work with current versions of GNU sed and with OSX/BSD sed.